# ORACLE SQL query-How to use select query to get all the data also with "(null)" value replaced by '~'

Tags: mysql, oracle

```
SELECT
   e.property 
   ,CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT  e.property  FROM SERVICES.ELEMENT E
                 WHERE E.property is null)
        THEN e.property
        ELSE '~'
   END AS OUTPUT  
  FROM SERVICES.ELEMENT E
```

How to use select query to get all the data also with "(null)" value replaced by '~'
i need to select the all the data also with the null value replaced by '~'

Thank You.

Comment: why a subselect? `select case when e.property is null then '~' else e.property`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `NVL` (or `COALESCE`)?

```
SELECT
  e.property,
  nvl(e.property, '~') as output
FROM 
  SERVICES.ELEMENT E
```